# Authentication y Cloud Firestore mismo id android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-auth

```
public void ContinuatTarjeta(View view) {

        String nombres = etNombre.getText().toString();
        String apellidos = etApellidos.getText().toString();
        String correo = etCorreo.getText().toString();
        String password = etContraseña.getText().toString();

        if(!nombres.isEmpty() && !apellidos.isEmpty() && !correo.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()){
                if (password.length() >=6){
                        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(correo,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Map<String,Object > Cliente = new HashMap<>();
                                    Cliente.put("nombres", nombres);
                                    Cliente.put("apellidos", apellidos);
                                    Cliente.put("correo", correo);
                                    Cliente.put("password", password);

                                    String id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                                    db.collection("Cliente")
                                            .add(Cliente)
                                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Guardado Exitoso, id: "+documentReference.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                            })
                                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                    Log.e("FireApp","Error",e);
                                                }
                                            });

                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(registro.this, "Nose pudo registar este usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "El password debe tener al menos 6 caracteres", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Debe completar los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

> > Estoy haciendo el registro de una persona con FireStore por lo cual estoy trabajando con Authentication y Cloud Firestore el codigo se ejecuta pero el problema es que al momento de registar     FirebaseAuth; FirebaseFirestore sus id que se generan son diferentes ¿Hay alguna forma de registar para que los id coincidan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplemente reemplaza `db.collection("Cliente").add(Cliente)` por `db.collection("Cliente").document(id).set(Cliente)`